# How can I use the custom image as thumbnail for Youtube videos?

Tags: media, 9

i want to use custom image as thumbnail for remote video (youtube) in my paragraphs , I create one field called custom image under remote video and used the below code.

```php
if ($entity->bundle() === 'remote_video' && isset($entity->get('field_custom_image')->target_id)) {
  $entity->get('thumbnail')->target_id = $entity->get('field_optional_custom_image')->target_id;
}
```

The thumbnail image is replaced by a custom image in media view, but when I tried to use that media in page, it is still using the Youtube thumbnail image.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I set this up in the URL to Video Filter module (https://www.drupal.org/project/url_to_video_filter). You can examine the source code and JS to see how I did it. It's been a few years so I don't remember the specifics.

Comment: The thumbnail is determined by a MediaSource plugin (here's [oembed](https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/9.4.x/core/modules/media/src/Plugin/media/Source/OEmbed.php#L264) and here's [image](https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/9.4.x/core/modules/media/src/Plugin/media/Source/Image.php#L142) for comparison because it pulls from a field in the entity). It's that dropdown you select when you create a new media type. You just need to extend the oembed one and have it pull from a field on the entity like image. Then update the media type via config (since the dropdown is disabled after create).

Comment: @Joseph HI joseph , can you please give me some example on how to do that one  ?